# Facebook Access Token for a backend application

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, spring-social

I'm building an application that needs to query and fetch the Facebook public feed every hour or so. I only need read access to the public feed. I can make the query using the Access Token generated on the Graph Explorer page but that token expires after an hour or so. I know there is a way to get a 60 days token and use that, but that requires updating the token every 60 days.

Whats the correct way of doing this? All the material I have found so far assumes a front end application that needs a user's login authentication.

Comment: The correct way to do it is to update the token every 60 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get offline access token for facebook (unlike google).

You can get access token for 60 days, and when user asks for page that requires authentication, redirect him to login page.

In playframework you can do this with securesocial module (and i am sure there is social module for whatever server you choose to use).

Alternatively, you can extend the short-lived access token.

I am unsure of the technical details of how to do this, only that it is possible.
Maybe this link can help you:
[Facebook full permission AccessToken alternative to Offline access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187604/facebook-full-permission-accesstoken-alternative-to-offline-access-token)